# Piechart in JavaFX, setting Custom color results in null pointer for Node instance

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

Following is my code for adding custom color to the piechart but it results in nullpointer 
when I tried to get pd.getNode(); can not figure out what is the problem.

```
PieChart.Data pd  = new PieChart.Data(c, mapComp.get(c));
pd.getNode().setStyle( "-fx-pie-color: " + c + ";");
pieChartDataComp.add(pd);
```

here c is hex value of color in String form, mapComp is Map implementaion contains c string hex value as key and integer value.

I don't know why it is resulting in NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well a silly mistake, One has to set the style only after the chart is loaded otherwise the Node instance will be null.